# how to return a string from a function in jQuery as a parameter to the other jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a small issue: I need to pass the value of string from function A to function B which will take it as argument and use it.

I have tried the following but its not working.

```
   // first function (A)
   $("a#SayHello").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var x = function () {
               var dt = '{"ProductID": "' + $("input#ProductID").val() + '" , "AffiliationURL": "' + $("input#AffiliationURL").val() + '" , "Quantitiy": "' + $("input#Quantitiy").val() + '" , "PricePerUnit": "' + $("input#PricePerUnit").val() + '" , "commissionAmount": "' + $("input#commissionAmount").val() + '"}';
               return dt.toString();
           };
       alert(x);
       $.B(x);
   });

   // second function
   function B(dt) {

       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           data: dt,
           url: 'http://localhost:4528/WebSite1/WebService.asmx/InsertCommissionRecord',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
               alert(data.d);
               alert(XMLHttpRequest);

           },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(textStatus);
           }
       });
   };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure but your not executing the function, try this:

```
alert(x());
$.B(x());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$.B(x);
```

call x() and B() straight away:

```
B(x());
```

---

To be able to use `B()` like this: `$.B()` you need to add your function to jQuery's `$`:

```
$.B = function(){...
```

or

```
jQuery.B = function(){...
```

But it's generally not recommended to pollute `$` - it's much better to use your own namespace.

See here: [is-it-possible-to-create-a-namespace-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527089/is-it-possible-to-create-a-namespace-in-jquery)

Comment: I just did the following and it worked for me
 `$("a#SayHello").click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();

                var x = A();
             //    alert(x);
                 B(x);
             });

             // first function (A)
             function A() {
                 var dt = '{"ProductID": "' + $("input#ProductID").val() + '" , "AffiliationURL": "' + $("input#AffiliationURL").val() + '" , "Quantitiy": "' + $("input#Quantitiy").val() + '","commissionAmount": "' + $("input#commissionAmount").val() + '"}';
                 return dt.toString();
};`

Answer (score 0):

Try call the B function without " $. ", just `B()` , like any simple function.

Also, you can add an `alert(dt)` inside B() function, to check the data from parameter.