# How to create global namespaces or variables for HTML attributes/selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying set selectors as global variables or namespaces.. I am not really sure if this is the correct terminology or if I am approaching this properly.

I would like to be able to do something like the following...

```
$.namespaceA = $('#myFirstDiv');
$.namespaceB = $('#mySecondDiv');


function myFirstFunction(){
   $.namespaceA.hide();
   $.namespaceB.css();
}

function mySecondFunction(){
   $.namespaceB.show();
}
```

This is a very basic example of how I want to use them. Basically the end goal is to set a group of global selectors which can be easily used through multiple functions. I don't know if this is right or if this is ideal which is why I am asking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can refer to :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527089/is-it-possible-to-create-a-namespace-in-jquery

Comment: I have seen this but don't really understand it. Also maybe namespace isn't best. Maybe what I really need is variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply make the global var's? (They can hold jQuery wrapped sets without a problem)

```
// When creating variables holding wrapped sets it is common naming to have 
// a $ following it (I find this rather annoying, since you can't easily double click
// on the var, in order to copy/paste it etc, so I always use _ underscore (personal preference)

var _div1 = $('#myFirstDiv'); // you will see a lot of people do div1$
var _div2 = $('#mySecondDiv'); // or div2$ (signifying the jQuery wrapped set)

_div2.hide();

//These could be used within multiple functions etc... No need for namespaces here!

function Whatever () {
    console.log(_div1);
    _div1.css('background', '#000');
}

$('#linkTrigger').on('click', function () {
    Whatever(); 
    _div2.fadeIn();
});
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TjtQk/1/)

`$.nameSpaceHere` is more for if you are trying to -extend- jQuery and add your own utility functions of some sort.

Comment: Would I write it like _div1.hide(); or $(_div1).hide(); ?

Comment: Out of curiosity. What is the reasoning behind the underscore before the variable name?

Comment: You only need _div1, for it is already a jQuery object. Just edited the answer to explain why I like to add the underscores. Most people use $ after the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to mcpDESIGNS:

http://jsfiddle.net/nqrvf/

```
<div id="myFirstDiv">first</div>
<div id="mySecondDiv">second</div>

var namespaceA = $('#myFirstDiv');
var namespaceB = $('#mySecondDiv');

$("#myFirstDiv").click(function() {
  namespaceA.hide();
});

$("#mySecondDiv").click(function() {
  namespaceA.show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare global variable without "var" keyword.

```
div = $('#myFirstDiv');
```

we can declare variable it inside any function it act as global variable.